# How to use matplotlib show images when debugging in PDB?

Tags: python, matplotlib

when I use `spider` to debug my `python` program with images, I meet some trouble to use `matplotlib.pyplot` to show a new window for a image, the `plt.imshow()` function just can't give me a new window to show it, is there any settings to do that?
I tried to use `%matplotlib qt` in `iPython` console, but it is invalid in `pdb` or `idb`.

Comment: does `plt.pause(3)` work?  The issue is the integration with the gui event loop.

Comment: yeah, it's awesome, it works. Thank you so much~

Comment: I meet some new problems~_~.when I debug the py files, I can see the `plt.imshow()` give me a dialog after `plt.pause(3)` is called, but if i don't close the dialog and wait for 3 seconds, the dialog will turn to gray, fall into inactive, is there some methods to make it still active after the `pause()`?